# Changing navbar hover icon

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a code example that function in a way that if the link on the navbar has sub-options, there is a small '+' sign next to the link. When the user hovers over the link, this changes to a '-' and shows the sub-options in a dropdown. What I want to do is change this to a sort of yellow 'v' shape (Stays static no matter if the user hovers or not) but I'm not sure how to do it.

The code example I have is quite long and I know it's to do with the `a:before` and `a:after` parts of the CSS but I'm not sure exactly what I'd have to change. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://pastie.org/private/tsuwnney7kiibhiuaambjq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing that looks like a `+` or `-` is in fact a visual trick of two slim lines, one vertical on horizontal, superimposed, as coded here:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
```

To fix it, you need to do something like this:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
   /*you don't need this style anymore */
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
      position: absolute;
      top: 19px;
      right: 14px;
      display: block;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      background: url([your yellow triangle image icon path goes here]) no-repeat;
      content: '';
    }
```

You'll also need to remove the dynamic behavior you described which looks like it might be line 91 in your example code.